# list within a list: how to search the inner list?

Tags: java

EDIT2: I want to return the inner list instead of the outer list.

might be best explained with an example:

```
public class customer {
    private String customerName;
    private List<String> orders;
}

public class Class2 {
   private List<Customer> customers;
}
```

I can run a for loop on customers and then use stream on the orders object.

But is it possible to do a stream inside a stream search? :o

something like:

```
List<customers> searchResults = customersList
            .stream()
            .filter(
                customer -> customer.getOrders()
                    .stream()
                    ...
                    ...
            )
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Edit1: I tried the stream inside a stream in my code and it won't even compile. IntelliJ saying something like "bad return type in lambda expression: string cannot be converted into a boolean"

E

Comment: What did you try, and issue(s) did you encounter?

Comment: @ScottHunter edited original post

Answer (score 1):

Yes,it's possible.

You can e.g. define your predicate when it should be filtered:

```
  Predicate<Customer> customerPredicate = (customer) -> customer.getOrders()
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(condition);

        List<Customer> searchResults = customersList.stream()
                .filter(customerPredicate)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it, here are two.

- The first uses `mapMulti` which was added in Java 16. It takes a `BiConsumer<T, Consumer<R>>` In this case it acts like a map but does not have to provide a result and put something on the stream.  The loop and if statement (which acts as a filter) avoids nested streaming.
- `customer` is the streamed customer
- `consumer` places the result(s) on the map as required.
- Just iterate the orders and if found, place on the customer on the stream. The testing can be arranged to accommodate any scenario. In the following case, the first match returns the customer and the loop exits.

```
List<Customer> searchResults = customerList.stream()
        .<Customer>mapMulti((customer, consumer) -> {
            for (String order : customer.getOrders()) {
                if (order.equals("someAttribute")) {
                    consumer.accept(customer);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }).toList();
```

- For older versions of java, it can be done as follows with a nested stream to check the orders.
- filter on the customer and stream the orders.
- apply anyMatch (or whatever other test you want to on each order.

```
List<Customer> list = customerList
        .stream().filter(
                customer -> customer.getOrders()
                        .stream()
                        .anyMatch(order -> order
                                .contains("someAttribute")))
        .toList();
```